# Query returning same row twice as result

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm learning how to write sql joing and wrote the below Query.

```
SELECT patient.name, patient.address, patient.CONTACTNUMBER, patient.disease,
patient.joining FROM patient INNER JOIN add_doctor ON patient.DOCASSIGN = 4534543
```

Here the result I'm getting is

```
**NAME  ADDRESS     CONTACTNUMBER   DISEASE JOINING**
sdfdvd  sdfdfbdfgd  3243453         sdvdvbd 01-JUL-15
sdfdvd  sdfdfbdfgd  3243453         sdvdvbd 01-JUL-15
```

I'm confused on why there are two same rows returned as my query result. please let me know how can i fix it and also plese help me understand why it is printing the same row twice

patient Table

```
ID       NAME         DISEASE    ADDRESS    CONTACTNUMBER   DOCASSIGN   ROOMASSIGN  JOINING    DISCHARGE
5656    sdfdvd       sdvdvbd    sdfdfbdfgd       3243453    4534543      General    01-JUL-15   15-JUL-15
65654   rgdgdgvds   sdfdfdgdfdb 1123fdffdbfd    4556767      4545            VIP    08-JUL-15   15-JUL-15
```

Doctor Table

```
ID          NAME    ADDRESS        EMAIL    CONTACT       SPECIALITY    SALARY  PASSWORD
4534543 fggfhdfs    rgghfgjfdj  gfhgfhjg    4365457567  dfsfhgjgkgfk    435435  safgdgd
4545    aaaaaaaaa   dffgdsg       fdfgds    43535       dffssgdhgd      324234  dfdhgggfdh
```

Comment: include the two tables, so we can check the data

Comment: Provide RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server etc...), sample data and tables structure.

Comment: You must have two rows in your patient table where DOCASSIGN has the value 4534543.

Comment: patient.DOCASSIGN = 4534543 this record 2 times in your table .

Comment: Give join filter condition too along with data filter condition. Join filter condition based on columns in both tables.

Comment: Hi @excaliburCayote, sorry for the delayed reply, I'm using oracle DB and updated my question with tables

Comment: Hi @StanislovasKalašnikovas, sorry for the delayed reply, I'm using oracle DB and updated my question with tables

Answer (score 1):

The table "patient" you are querying contains at least two rows containing entries of the same values for name, address, CONTACTNUMBER, disease, joining. This is actually a data integrity problem. The patient table should not contain these two rows. If you like to show only one row in the result, you can do this by using `distinct()`

```
SELECT distinct(patient.name), 
       patient.address, 
       patient.CONTACTNUMBER, 
       patient.disease,
       patient.joining 
FROM patient INNER JOIN add_doctor 
    ON patient.DOCASSIGN = 4534543
```

Comment: Hi Tobias, Thank you verymuch this is working awesome as expected. I've a small question, `distinct` will eliminate all the duplicate values, but why in my output do i get a duplicated row, i mean any way without using distinct.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is ***NOT*** a function. It always works on all columns in the select list. Putting a single column in parentheses won't change anything. Your query is equivalent to `select distinct patient.name, (patient.address), ...`

Answer (score 1):

In TSQL an `INNER join` is evaluated in 2 logical phases

1. Cross join
2. Filter out rows which do not satisfy filter condition in `ON` clause.

To say if table `Patient` has row like:

```
NAME    ADDRESS     CONTACTNUMBER   DISEASE JOINING   DOCASSIGN
dfdvd   sdfdfbdfgd  3243453         sdvdvbd 01-JUL-15 4534543
```

And table `add_doctor` has rows like:

```
DOCNAME
Test   
Test2
```

so for inner join first a cross join will be done with interim results as:

```
Step1: patient Cross JOIN add_doctor
```

This will result in `1*2 = 2` rows as:

```
NAME    ADDRESS     CONTACTNUMBER   DISEASE JOINING   DOCASSIGN DOCNAME 
dfdvd   sdfdfbdfgd  3243453         sdvdvbd 01-JUL-15 4534543   Test    
dfdvd   sdfdfbdfgd  3243453         sdvdvbd 01-JUL-15 4534543   Test2
```

In second logical phase of `Filerting based on ON` clause as both the rows qualifies the filter condition

```
Step2: ON patient.DOCASSIGN = 4534543
```

the final result has two rows with duplicate data:

```
NAME    ADDRESS     CONTACTNUMBER   DISEASE JOINING
sdfdvd  sdfdfbdfgd  3243453         sdvdvbd 01-JUL-15
sdfdvd  sdfdfbdfgd  3243453         sdvdvbd 01-JUL-15
```

To remove duplicate data use [DISTINCT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx) keyword and re-write the query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name,
                p.address, 
                p.CONTACTNUMBER, 
                p.disease,
           p.joining 
FROM patient as p 
INNER JOIN add_doctor a ON p.DOCASSIGN = 4534543
```

You can refer to the different logical phases in which a query is processed [here...](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf)

Comment: Hi Mini, thanks for the answer, This is not working , I'm getting the error as  `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`, I'm using oracle db